# Why there is no `char16_t` variant of C++17 `from_chars` / `to_chars`?

Tags: c++17

There is a very similar question on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/fh5h8q/why_there_is_no_wchar_t_variant_of_to_chars_and/ - but unfortunately, it mentioned `wchar_t`, and that drowned in unrelated discussion how bad `wchar_t` is - even though the question itself mentioned also other character types.

So the question is: C++17 introduced the `char`-based `from_chars` and `to_chars`; but decided to not make them templated on character type (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r5.html). The existing libraries have test code that explicitly check that other character types are not handled (e.g., [this libstdc++ test code](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/from_chars/1_c%2B%2B20_neg.cc;h=04d9ba6e74ae41a78f8b6c6d929be1821bca871c;hb=HEAD)). What is the rationale to do that? Why is it not OK to use them on arrays of char16_t (if there is such a data); why would one need to copy the data to `char`s to enable use of the library functions, introduced long after char16_t etc. were introduced?

This question is independent on any discussion which character type is "best". There is not always a choice which character type to use.